# Code migration from visual studio 2012 to 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, migration, coded-ui-tests

VISUAL STUDIO 2013 :After code migration from visual studio 2012 to 2013 ,When I am building my solution, its showing build successful. But when I am trying to run a test case, it showing no test cases found. error message: MStestadapter could not find test cases in class" {respective class}". Can anyone help if u faced the same issue or any possible solution?

Comment: Are the tests returning type `Task` or are they `async void`?

Comment: Maybe this post could help you : http://dailywebtips.blogspot.fr/2012/09/visual-studio-2012-express-error.html